# Check if default value for tikz key is used

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzducks

> Background story: I am currently implementing the suggestions of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/171841/145641

How to change the line

```
\ifdefined\duck@hair\let\duck@eyebrow=\duck@hair\fi
```

so that it only applies if no colour is explicitly given for `\duck@eyebrow`

---

**Application**

I'd like to draw hair and eyebrows and I would like the following behaviour: If
no colour is explicitly specified it should check if `\duck@hair` is defined and take the colour of that or if `\duck@hair` is not defined it should fall back to the default colour.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\duck}[1][]{\tikzset{/duck/.cd,#1}\duck@draw}

\newif\ifduck@shorthair
\newif\ifduck@eyebrow

\tikzset{
    /duck/.cd,
    shorthair/.code         = \duck@shorthairtrue           \def\duck@hair{#1},
    eyebrow/.code               = \duck@eyebrowtrue           \def\duck@eyebrow{#1},
    % setting defaults %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    shorthair/.default      = green,
    eyebrow/.default            = blue,
}

\def\duck@draw{
    % short hair %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \ifduck@shorthair
        \path[fill=\duck@hair] 
        (1.3947,1.4175).. controls (1.4546,1.4518) and (1.4699,1.6566) .. 
        (1.4343,1.7992).. controls (1.2528,2.5033) and (0.2339,2.2710) .. 
        (0.4151,1.5907).. controls (0.4345,1.8709) and (0.7421,2.0999) .. 
        (0.9494,1.9054).. controls (1.2241,1.6476) and (1.3316,1.3814) .. 
        (1.3947,1.4175) -- cycle;
    \fi
    %
    % eye brow %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \ifdefined\duck@hair\let\duck@eyebrow=\duck@hair\fi
    \ifduck@eyebrow
        \draw[line width=2,color=\duck@eyebrow,line cap=round] 
            (0.96,1.70) -- (0.82,1.77);
        \draw[line width=2,color=\duck@eyebrow,line cap=round] 
            (0.50,1.81) -- (0.60,1.82);
    \fi 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[eyebrow]
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[shorthair=red, eyebrow]
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[shorthair=pink, eyebrow=red]
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[shorthair, eyebrow=red]
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Desired output:** 
red eyebrows in the last two images

Comment: Maybe this helps `\pgfkeys{/handlers/.default/.code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@def}{#1}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A really bad approach

```
\tikzset{
    /duck/.cd,
    shorthair/.store in=\duck@hair,
    eyebrow/.store in=\duck@eyebrow
}

\def\duck@draw{
    \ifdefined\duck@hair
        \path[fill=green,fill=\duck@hair]
        (1.3947,1.4175).. controls (1.4546,1.4518) and (1.4699,1.6566) .. 
        (1.4343,1.7992).. controls (1.2528,2.5033) and (0.2339,2.2710) .. 
        (0.4151,1.5907).. controls (0.4345,1.8709) and (0.7421,2.0999) .. 
        (0.9494,1.9054).. controls (1.2241,1.6476) and (1.3316,1.3814) .. 
        (1.3947,1.4175) -- cycle;
    \else
        \def\duck@hair{}
    \fi
    \ifdefined\duck@eyebrow
        \draw[line width=2,line cap=round,draw=blue,draw=\duck@hair,draw=\duck@eyebrow]
            (0.96,1.70) -- (0.82,1.77)
            (0.50,1.81) -- (0.60,1.82);
    \fi 
}
```

The logic is really bad. The point is: `draw=` and `fill=` will test if the argument is empty. So you do not have to test yourself.

Comment: Small improvement: replace `\path[fill=green,fill=\duck@hair]` by `\fill[green,\duck@hair]`. Now the pgfkeys parser will do the job for you.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming one knows the default value, another of if case does the trick:

```
\pgfkeys{/duck/eyebrow/.@def/.get=\duck@test}
\ifx\duck@eyebrow\duck@test
    \ifdefined\duck@hair\let\duck@eyebrow=\duck@hair\fi
\fi%
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\duck}[1][]{\tikzset{/duck/.cd,#1}\duck@draw}

\newif\ifduck@shorthair
\newif\ifduck@eyebrow

\tikzset{
    /duck/.cd,
    shorthair/.code         = \duck@shorthairtrue           \def\duck@hair{#1},
    eyebrow/.code               = \duck@eyebrowtrue           \def\duck@eyebrow{#1},
    % setting defaults %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    shorthair/.default      = green,
    eyebrow/.default            = blue,
}
\def\duck@draw{
% short hair %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ifduck@shorthair
    \path[fill=\duck@hair] 
    (1.3947,1.4175) .. controls (1.4546,1.4518) and (1.4699,1.6566) .. 
    (1.4343,1.7992) .. controls (1.2528,2.5033) and (0.2339,2.2710) .. 
    (0.4151,1.5907) .. controls (0.4345,1.8709) and (0.7421,2.0999) .. 
    (0.9494,1.9054) .. controls (1.2241,1.6476) and (1.3316,1.3814) .. 
    (1.3947,1.4175) -- cycle;
\fi
%
% eye brow %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pgfkeys{/duck/eyebrow/.@def/.get=\duck@test}
\ifx\duck@eyebrow\duck@test
    \ifdefined\duck@hair\let\duck@eyebrow=\duck@hair\fi
\fi%
\ifduck@eyebrow
    \draw[line width=2,color=\duck@eyebrow,line cap=round] 
        (0.96,1.70) -- (0.82,1.77);
    \draw[line width=2,color=\duck@eyebrow,line cap=round] 
        (0.50,1.81) -- (0.60,1.82);
\fi 
}% from `\def\duck@draw{` at the very beginning 

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[eyebrow]
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[shorthair=red, eyebrow]
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[shorthair=pink, eyebrow=red]
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[shorthair, eyebrow=red]
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or replace `\def\duck@test{blue}` by `\pgfkeys{/duck/eyebrow/.@def/.get=\duck@test}`.

Comment: @Symbol1 That's a great idea! Works wonderful!